# TabController calling initState again if tabs are clicked in sequence

Tags: android, flutter

I'm new to flutter. I needed my app to contain 4 different widgets. Each widget has it own data to read from the server in the initState method. First time the layout is loaded initState is called and gets the data from the server fine. So all is working except that I noticed the initState is called again if I click on non-adjacent tabs.

For example: If I Clicked on Tab 3 then Tab 2, after loading them the first time, the previous state is loaded fine and initState is not called again. However, If I clicked Tab 4 then Tab 1 or Tab 2, after loading them the first time, the initState of both tabs is called again and goes to the server to re-fetch the data.

I tried to use *if (this.mounted)* in the initState but it is evaluated as true and still fetches data from the server again if tabs aren't selected in the same order.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'app_layouts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage2()));
}

class HomePage2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePage2State createState() => _HomePage2State();
}

class _HomePage2State extends State<HomePage2> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  static final List<MyTab> myTabs = [
    MyTab(tab: Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home)), tabView: SimpleTabView()),
    MyTab(tab: Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today)), tabView: SimpleTab2View()),
    MyTab(tab: Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.message)), tabView: SimpleTabView()),
    MyTab(tab: Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.note)), tabView: SimpleTab2View()),
  ];
  var _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: myTabs.length, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      //I added a custom tab controller, as I need to be notified with tab change events
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test Tab Issue'),
        bottom: TabBar(
          tabs: myTabs.map((tab) => tab.tab).toList(),
          controller: _tabController,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: myTabs.map((tab) => tab.tabView).toList(),
        controller: _tabController,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyTab {
  Tab tab;
  Widget tabView;
  MyTab({this.tab, this.tabView});
}

class SimpleTabView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SimpleTabViewState createState() => _SimpleTabViewState();
}

class _SimpleTabViewState extends State<SimpleTabView> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  bool isDoingTask = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('initState called ...');
    if (this.mounted) {
      this.getTask();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Tab view'),
        Loader(showLoading: isDoingTask),
      ],
    );
  }

  void getTask() async {
    setState(() {
      isDoingTask = true;
    });
    print("${new DateTime.now()} Pause for 3 seconds");
    await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    if (!this.mounted) return null;
    setState(() {
      isDoingTask = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}

//Exactly the same as SimpleTabView except the class name
class SimpleTab2View extends StatefulWidget {....
```

I expect the initState method to not be called again since I'm already using with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, and it was called the first time already.

Comment: This will work as expected if you switch to the `master` channel. The fix doesn't seem to have landed on `stable` yet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please share a link for that master branch? And if there is any expectation when that would go to `stable`, if that is published?

Comment: You can switch to `master` channel using the command `flutter channel master` in your terminal. I don't know when it will be in stable.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. This worked. Waiting for the stable release one day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed on `master` as mentioned on this [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32290#issuecomment-491880194).